# The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

> Error Number: 1222
>   The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

This is controller

```
    <?php
    class Autocomplete extends CI_Controller{
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('datacomplete');
        }

        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('view_demo');
        }
        public function GetCountryName(){
            $keyword=$this->input->post('keyword');
            $data=$this->datacomplete->GetRow($keyword); 

            echo json_encode($data);
        }

    }
    ?>
```

This is model

```
        <?php
    class Datacomplete extends CI_Model{

        public function GetRow($keyword) {        
           $this->db->select('collg_name,city,state,country as type');
           $this->db->from('tbl_college');
           $this->db->like("collg_name",$keyword);
           $this->db->or_like('city',$keyword,'after');
           $this->db->or_like('state',$keyword,'after');
           $this->db->or_like('country',$keyword,'after');
           $query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
           $this->db->select('course_offrd_name,category_name,subcategory_name');
           $this->db->from('tbl_course_offered');
           $this->db->like("course_offrd_name",$keyword);
           $this->db->or_like('category_name',$keyword,'after');
           $this->db->or_like('subcategory_name',$keyword,'after');
           $query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
           $result = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2);
           return $result->result();
        }
    }
```

This is view

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/custom.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body style="background-color: #000000;">
            <div class="row">
            <center><h2 style="color: #fff;">AUTOCOMPLETE FORM FROM DATABASE USING CODEIGNITER AND AJAX</h2></center>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="margin-top: 200px;">

                        <label class="control-lable" style="color: #fff;">Country Name</label>
                        <input style="height:70px" type="text" id="country" autocomplete="off" name="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to get an Ajax call of Countries">        
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu txtcountry" style="margin-left:15px;margin-right:0px;" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu"  id="DropdownCountry"></ul>
    </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

    This is custom.js

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#country").keyup(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/codeajax/autocomplete/GetCountryName",
                data: {
                    keyword: $("#country").val()
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $('#DropdownCountry').empty();
                        $('#country').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                        $('#DropdownCountry').dropdown('toggle');
                    }
                    else if (data.length == 0) {
                        $('#country').attr("data-toggle", "");
                    }
                    $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                        if (data.length >= 0)
                            $('#DropdownCountry').append('<li role="displayCountries" ><a role="menuitem dropdownCountryli" class="dropdownlivalue">' + value['name'] + '</a></li>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        $('ul.txtcountry').on('click', 'li a', function () {
            $('#country').val($(this).text());
        });
    });
```

Here i m trying to search a keyword from three table using codeigniter and ajax.
I'm getting that error in the `model`

How can I solve this issue?

Also, if the issue is solved whether my search will fetch the data from database.
What is wrong in the code?

Comment: in console i m getting this error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)    autocomplete/GetCountryName:1

Comment: in union all select have same no of columns, you have 4 columns in first select and 3 columns in second select

Comment: @M.Hemant in uniuon all select same no of columns? not understood

Comment: @M.Hemant  there is limit in select no of colums....what i have to do to make it work

Comment: Did you tried with same no.of column? both select must have 3 columns

Answer (score 1):

You have to use same column number in your `select` statement as following

First `select` you use 4 columns :

```
$this->db->select('collg_name,city,state,country as type');


second select you use 3 columns : 


$this->db->select('course_offrd_name,category_name,subcategory_name');


class Datacomplete extends CI_Model{

    public function GetRow($keyword) {        
       $this->db->select('collg_name,city,state,country as type');
       $this->db->from('tbl_college');
       $this->db->like("collg_name",$keyword);
       $this->db->or_like('city',$keyword,'after');
       $this->db->or_like('state',$keyword,'after');
       $this->db->or_like('country',$keyword,'after');
       $query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
       $this->db->select('course_offrd_name,category_name,subcategory_name, null as type');
       $this->db->from('tbl_course_offered');
       $this->db->like("course_offrd_name",$keyword);
       $this->db->or_like('category_name',$keyword,'after');
       $this->db->or_like('subcategory_name',$keyword,'after');
       $query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
       $result = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2);
       return $result->result();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `'$result = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2);'` you are combining 2 table results but in 1st table you are selecting `4` columns & in 2nd table you are selecting 3 columns.

When You combine using `UNION` then it will result into records & here both table columns are different  and also the column count is different. To use UNION you have to select same column count & if possible then select same columns only.

In above situation error occure bcz:

```
                     + collg_name + city + state + type +
---------------------+------------+------+-------+------+
1st table record     + A          + b    + c     + d    +
---------------------+------------+------+-------+------+
2nd table record     + x          + y    + z     + -    +
```

2nd table don`t have last column value

Union execute in below condition:

```
SELECT City FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT City FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY City;
```

Result :

```
        + City +
1st tbl | city1|
1st tbl | city2|
2st tbl | city3|
```